# "Because of" or "Due to"?

Tags: grammar

I can't come to the office today due to some personal reason.

https://www.englishpage.net/showthread.php?14817-I-can-t-come-to-the-office-today-due-to-some-personal-reason

Coming to the office is a verb so it will take the adverbial prepositional phrase "because of". As far as I think.

Comment: [to due a personal reason] no some

Answer (score 2):

In modern English, "due to" and "because of" can be used interchangeably.  No one would confuse the meaning of the sentence if you use one or the other.  [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/due%20to) defines them as identical.  [Oxford](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/58238?redirectedFrom=due+to#eid6088656) also defines it the same.

Historically, "due to" was an adjective phrase and used to describe nouns.  Rephrasing your sentence would highlight the different use cases a bit more clearly:

> My not coming to work is due to illness.
>
> I am not coming to work because of illness.

This is not the case in modern English as the two have become synonymous.